# React ssr(next)-getInitialProps insert a reactNode to props render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In next(react ssr), I try to render a page use like this

```js
// this common element, so much project use this, in my private node_modules
const Header = ({ result }) => <div>{result}</div>;

const renderComponent = async () => {
  // mock some request
  const result = await Promise.resolve(10);
  return <Header result={result} />;
};

static getInitialProps = async ctx => {

  return {
    Element: await renderComponent()
  }

}

render({Element}){
  console.log(Element)
  return Element
}
```

- In server side, correct render and console is

```js
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function: Header],
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: { result: 10 },
  _owner: null,
  _store: {} }
```

- In webside dom render correct one time, but soon throw error to empty page, console is

```js
{key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, _owner: null, _store: {…}}
key: null
ref: null
props: {result: 10}
_owner: null
_store: {}
__proto__: Object
```

so, how to keep correct to render the common element.

Comment: I noticed that what `getInitialProps` returns will be serialised at the client on first load (JSON.stringify) so if it returns `{Component:()=><SomeThing />}` then it won't have `Component`. It will also break `{result:<SomeThing />}`. You can return `result` and do `<Header result={this.props.result} />` in the render function of your page.

Comment: yes, as you say, the server memory can't share to the web memory.next will render two time.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is as HMR said, and get your data inside getInitialProps, this will render the component twice, and you need to handle the empty/null state yourself;

```
static getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const result = await Promise.resolve(10);
  return {
    result
  }
}

render() {

  // Handle empty state;
  if(!result) return null; // Or <EmptyPage />

  return (
     <Header result={result} />
  )
}
```

Comment: It will render in web side is empty page.